# c# TcpClient Post returning empty results

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, tcpclient

I have the following code:

```
string url = "https://myurl.com/is/here/example?param1=100&param2=200";

string post = "POST " + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
              "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" +
              "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n" +
              "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n" +
              "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" +
              "Host: myurl.com\r\n" +
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0\r\n" +
              "Content-type: application/json\r\n" +
              "X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET\r\n" +
              "X-MY-CUSTOM-HEADER: headervalue\r\n\r\n";

TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient("myurl.com", 443);

string returnData = string.Empty;
using (SslStream stream  = new SslStream(tcp.GetStream()))
{
    //Authenticate here...

    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);

    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.ReadByte();

    data = new byte[4096];
    var n = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data, 0, n))
    {
        ms.ReadByte();
        ms.ReadByte();

        using (DeflateStream df = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(df))
        {
            returnData = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}

tcp.Close();
```

However, the response is always empty. Is the post string correct? What am I missing here?

Edit:

I'm using SslStream and it seems to be retrieving data. However, Is there a way to just read till all data is received instead of

Comment: Is there a reason that you're trying to do this with `TcpClient` rather than using something that talks HTTP(S) natively?

Comment: Don't do it yourself, use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm already using HttpWebRequest and it works fine. However I want to try the same using TcpClient to see if there is a performance difference.

Comment: If you could write more performant code using `TcpClient` than `HttpWebRequest` achieves, why would the developers of that class not have already done so and put that implementation inside `HttpWebRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're declaring the length of content to by the length of your URL (when expressed as UTF-8), rather than whatever is in the `post` body

If the content is not as long as the content-length header indicates, I would expect the remote server to wait for the rest of the content.

You're also connecting to port 443, and your URL starts 'https' but you don't appear to be making any attempt to do the SSL negotiation.

Comment: Ok, The Content-Length header is redundant so I removed it. How does SSL negotiation look like?